# svnlook always returns an error and no output

Tags: c#, svn, pre-commit-hook

I'm running this small C# test program launched from a pre-commit batch file

```
private static int Test(string[] args)
{
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "svnlook.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        ErrorDialog = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        Arguments = "help"
    };

    using (var svnlook = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
    {
        string output = svnlook.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        svnlook.WaitForExit();

        Console.Error.WriteLine("svnlook exited with error 0x{0}.", svnlook.ExitCode.ToString("X"));
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Current output is: {0}", string.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "empty" : output);

        return 1;
    }
}
```

I am deliberately calling `svnlook help` and forcing an error so I can see what is going on when committing.

When this program run, SVN displays

> svnlook exited with error 0xC0000135.
>
> Current output is: empty

I looked up the error 0xC0000135 and it mean `App failed to initialize properly` although it wasn't specific to svnhook.

Why is `svnlook help` not returning anything? Does it fail when executed through another process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar app that is called that uses the svnlook and it works fine , 2 things to check/try are.

1. Check that svnlook is included in your systempath (Test this by opening a command prompt and typing svnlook and checking if it outputs the usual (Type 'svnlook help' for usage))
2. Try doing a re install of your svn tools , it maybe possible that svnlook got corrupted somehow.